# Override an image to fill a primefaces calendar button

Tags: css, primefaces

In my application I have many calendar components with the ShowOn option so I want to override an image to fill the whole button so here's my actual code:

```
.ui-icon-calendar {
    background-image: url('../../resources/images/calIc.png') !important;

    background-position: center center !important;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

[actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALZP9.png)

Comment: And the problem is? (besides that it does not fill the whole button)

Comment: @Kukeltje the only problem is that the image doesn't fill the whole button

Comment: width: 30px? background-size? Tried all that? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp Please show the **generated** relevant html (client-side) and hope the css experts can help. This is **not** a PrimeFaces issue

Comment: @Kukeltje yes i tried to increase the width and background-size but the result still the same, any way thank you so much for your comments